Stopping a Python thread from class when an object gets deleted
I'm building a class which has a thread that does some work in the background. I want this thread to be deleted whenever the class is also deleted or goes out of scope. The code I'm using is equivalent to this:
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import sys

class Test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self._running_thread = False
        self._thread = None
    
    def _workFunc (self):
        while self._running_thread:
            print("Working...")
            sleep(1)
    
    def startThread (self):
        self._running_thread = True
        self._thread = Thread(target=self._workFunc)
        self._thread.start()
    
    def stopThread (self):
        self._running_thread = False
        self._thread.join()
    
    def __del__ (self):
        self.stopThread()

def main ():
    test = Test()
    test.startThread()
    sleep(3)
    print("Going out of scope!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())

What I expect is that the thread is started, the working message gets printed three or four times, and then the test object goes out of scope, __del__ gets called, and the execution of the program resumes once the thread has finished. What happens instead is that the "Going out of scope!" message is printed after three seconds, but the thread keeps printing "working" indefinitely. What is happening, and how could I get the effect that I'm looking for?

I suggest you read this. In essence, relying on __del__ to stop the thread is not viable. If you debug your code you'll note that __del__ isn't being called

@SIGHUP I was suspecting something like that. The thing is that the object is controlled by a different library (streamlit) that executes a program loop. As far as I know, there is no way of controlling when the loop ends to call some cleaning function (like the stopThread method). The __del__ method or something equivalent seems to be the best option...

Please then give us a minimal example of how you use this object with Streamlit.

Are you saying that you don't know when this thread needs to be stopped? If you know where your class instance is going to go out of scope, you can deal with the stopping mechanism yourself

You should use daemon threads because they are automatically terminated when the main program exits. This ensures that your program doesn't keep running indefinitely.
When creating your thread, simply specify it as a daemon by passing daemon=true as an argument.
like:
def startThread(self):
    self._running_thread = True
    self._thread = Thread(target=self._workFunc, daemon=True)
    self._thread.start()

Read more here

I think the requirement is to stop the thread before the program ends

This works! Thanks

@Cnoob welcome!
